# Mime type of .mjs file from Azure App service is 'text/plain' (only in Production server)

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer in my Angular app deployed on Azure app service (Linux).

**angular.json** config (as per docs)
[image]

The **.mjs** files are included in assets/ folder and works fine in development mode. However, when deployed on production server, it gives the following error:

*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

I tried configuring the mime types on Azure but since it does not use a reverse proxy such as ngnix, I am unable to configure mjs to be returned as **application/javascript**. Since its Linux, web.config doesnt work either.

Is there a way from Azure Portal to configure this?

Comment: You can find web.config file in KUDU console.Can you cross check once.

Answer (score 0):

MIME-type issues with .mjs files on Azure App Service (Linux) are due to the Startup Command in Stack settings of Configuration.

[image]
instead of

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa

It should have pointed to the dist folder, so changing it to

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa

- Open your terminal or command prompt and run the following command to install the Angular CLI globally:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

- Run the following command to create a new Angular project. Replace "my-angular-app" with your desired project name:

bashCopy code

`ng new my-angular-app`

Follow the prompts to set up your project. You can choose options like routing and styling during this process

`cd my-angular-app`

Run the following command to serve your Angular app locally:

bashCopy code

`ng serve`

Your Angular app will be accessible at `http://localhost:4200/` by default. Open this URL in your browser, and you should see the default Angular app.
[image]

**Local:**
[image]

**Deployment Status:**

Deployment of the [web](https://dailydotnettips.com/deploy-azure-web-apps-from-visual-studio-code/) app to Azure from Visual Studio [Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) has been completed.
[image]

Enter `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa` under **Startup Command** and click save

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

**With ngx-extended-pdf-viewer:**

Below is the full code for an [Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) [project](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2021/how-to-build-an-angular-pdf-viewer-with-pdfjs/) that uses   `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` to display a [PDF](https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/getting-started)

- code taken from [git](https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/ngx-web-example-angular).

Open the `angular.json` file and update the `assets` section under `projects`

```json
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
        "output": "/assets/"
    }
],
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from  '@angular/core';

  

@Component({

selector: 'app-root',

templateUrl: './app.component.html',

styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export  class AppComponent {

title = 'ngx-pdf-viewer';

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
  [src]="'assets/example.pdf'"
  [useBrowserLocale]="true"
  [textLayer]="true"
  [showHandToolButton]="true"
  [showPresentationModeButton]="true"
  [showDownloadButton]="false"
>
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

**Local:**

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not use azure but i had the same error.
The problem is, that in my mime.types file there was no content-type mapping to .mjs files. After adding this (application/javascript) it worked just fine!
I hope it helps